# How Do I display dates of all days of week if I have a start date in JavaScript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an hidden field which is holding value of a date which is start date for pay period. Now I have to display that date and whole week dates based on start date.  Till now I'm displaying days of week but now I need to display dates instead of  days. How do I acheive this? I just need to display month and day mm/dd next to each day. Like **12/01 S**

Hidden filed value is the first day that means Saturday and other dates should follow that day till startdate+6 i.e, till F

```
<div class="form-group" id="buttonsr">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
        <div class='input-group input-group-sm'>
            <span class="input-group-addon">Week</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekGroup" id="week_sat">S</button>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week_sun">S</button>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekGroup" id="week1_mon">M</button>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekGroup" id="week_tue">T</button>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekGroup" id="week_wen">W</button>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekGroup" id="week_thu">T</button>
        <button class="btn" name="WeekGroup" id="week_fri">F</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a real answer to your question, therefore I post it as a comment; but have you looked at http://momentjs.com/ already? Datemanipulation made easy.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but this isn't about just formatting date. I want to display the date in mm/dd format next to day like 12/01 S. S is saturday

Comment: I don't understand how that isn't just formatting date

Comment: Here you go: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: Where are you displaying this information? do you have something we can start with?

Comment: How do I display the date next to day? That is my primary requirement.I tried like this Date($('[id$=hdnStartDt]').val()) S. This is giving entire text but not date

Comment: ... with string concatenation and innerHTML?

Comment: I want to display as text of button like for all days of week like 12/01 S 12/02 S 12/03 M..

Comment: how to do this with innerHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle for you [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rmX36/10/)

And the code

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

//This is just for testing, here you set the day!!
dd= 28;
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //here you must add 1 for january!
//This is just for testing, here you set the month!!
mm = 06;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
//adds a zero in front if less than 10
if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

//adds a zero in front if less than 10
if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 
var buttonContainer = {};
buttonContainer[0] = document.getElementById("week_sat");
buttonContainer[1] = document.getElementById("week_sun");
buttonContainer[2] = document.getElementById("week1_mon");
buttonContainer[3] = document.getElementById("week_tue");
buttonContainer[4] = document.getElementById("week_wen");
buttonContainer[5] = document.getElementById("week_thu");
buttonContainer[6] = document.getElementById("week_fri");
//add to all buttons!
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)   
{
    var addedDays = dd + i;
    var monthDays = daysInMonth(mm,yyyy);
    var newMonth = mm;    
    if(monthDays < addedDays)
    {
         newMonth =  parseInt(mm) + 1;
         addedDays = (addedDays - monthDays);
         if(addedDays<10) {
            addedDays='0'+addedDays
         }

    }


    today = newMonth +'/'+ addedDays;
    buttonContainer[i].innerHTML = today + buttonContainer[i].innerHTML;
}

function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but once the day date passes last day of month it is not changing to next month like if 12/31 is last day of month next day is 12/32 and 12/33 and follows..how to fix this?

Comment: @user3154990 True I will update the code to handle that specfic case later today.

Comment: Thank you very much...its working..can you also show me how to change color of button when clicked. Sorry for late response.